# Vuex: what is the best way to update multiple state properties in VUEX mutation?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have a namespaced Vuex mutation and I am trying to update multiple state properties at once. In order to avoid repetition I would like to use the ES6 spread operator. Object.assign works as expected but the spread operator fails to update the VUEX state. Here is the code which illustrates the problem:

```js
const authorizationModule = {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    status: '',
    jwt: '',
    user: {
      email: ''
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    AUTH_SUCCESS(state, payload) {
      const { jwt, user } = payload;

      // Too much repitition (needs to be abstracted)
      state.jwt = jwt;
      state.status = 'status';
      state.user = user;

      // 1. Object.assign works correctly
      // state = Object.assign(state, {
      //   jwt,
      //   status: 'success',
      //   user
      // });

      // 2. Spread operator does not work
      // let newState = {
      //   ...state,
      //   jwt,
      //   status: 'success',
      //   user
      // }
      // state = newState
    },
  }
}
```

It's interesting because I threw a debugger into the code and inspected it in the browser. It seems like the return value for the spread operator is returning a different object. The Object.assign implementation seems to have getter and setter functions in the object (which is the reason it is working as intended). Here is an image of my console:

[image: Object.assign vs. Spread Operator]

You can see that the object in the 2nd example is missing certain Vuex getter and setting methods.

So the question remains: is it possible to use the spread operator in this context to update multiple state properties in Vuex?

Comment: To answer the final question - no - as you've seen, it is not - besides, `Object.assign` code works just fine (and you don't need `state = Object.assign(state,...` just `Object.assign(state,...`

Comment: _"I would like to use the ES6 spread operator"_... you can't. `state` is an argument to your mutation. Re-assigning it does not modify the previous reference. You can only modify its properties in order to make persistent changes

Comment: _"Too much repitition (needs to be abstracted)"_ that's debatable, but regardless, but Object.assign is the way.